# ASP.NET page crashes with MySql connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, monodevelop

I am trying to write a dashboard with information about the website's hits and where people come from etc.

I wrote the following page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Daschboard.Board" MasterPageFile="~/site.master" %>        
<asp:Content id="main" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="main">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="updateableWidgets">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="WidgetsTable">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

With the following code behind:

```
using Widgets;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Daschboard
{
public partial class Board : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected List<IWidget> widgets;
    private MySqlConnection db = new MySqlConnection (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["mySql"]);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        widgets = new List<IWidget>();
        BuildWidgtTable();
        var WidgetThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(this.InitWidgets));
        WidgetThread.Start();
    }

    private string BuildWidgtTable ()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
        db.Open ();
        var tableName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["DatabaseSiteName"];
        var query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ", Widget WHERE " + tableName + ".WidgetID = Widget.WidgetID";
        var command = new MySqlCommand (query, db);
        var result = command.ExecuteReader ();
        while (result.Read()) {
            widgets.Add(getWidget(result.GetString(4)));
        }
        db.Close ();

        sb.Append("<table>\n");

        sb.Append("</table>");

        result.Close();
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private void InitWidgets ()
    {
        db.Open();
        foreach (var widget in widgets) {
            var siteId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["siteID"];
            var query = "SELECT * FROM Values, Widget WHERE       Widget.WidgetID = Values.WidgetID AND SiteID = " + siteId;
            var command = new MySqlCommand(query, db);
            var result = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(result.Read()){
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            result.Close();
            widget.Init ("1");
        }
        db.Close();
    }

    private IWidget getWidget (string fileName)
    {
        IWidget widget = null;
        switch (fileName) {
        case "PageHits":
            widget = new PageHits();
            break;
        case "SiteHits":
            widget = new SiteHits();
            break;
        }
        return widget;
    }
}
}
```

When I run this something goes wrong; the debugger stops working without a good error. 
It does load the widgets from the database but it doesn't get the values from the database.

I am using Monodevelop on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the widget initialization method in a separate thread (`InitWidgets` method). The page might have already finished rendering when this method executes. If you want to use asynchronous operations in ASP.NET I would recommend you reading about [`Asynchronous Pages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) on MSDN. The idea is to mark your WebForm as asynchronous by setting `Async="true"` in your Page directive (`<%@ Page Async="true" ... %>`) and then use the `RegisterAsyncTask` method on your web form.

Comment: My thought about this was to initilaize the widgets after the page was rendered, but if i am reading this correctly it wil stil wait for all threads to be finished before the page is shown on the site. Do i need to use somthing else so i can update things after the page is loaded without post back's?

Comment: No, that's not correct. The page will finish render to the client, but the thread continue to run on your server. When the thread finishes executing on the server, you can no longer modify anything on the client because the page was already rendered. Please read the article I have provided you in my answer to better understand how asynchronous pages work in ASP.NET. But if you want your page to render and then initialize your widgets on demand later, you will have to use AJAX and not any threads on the server. Read about UpdatePanels in this case.

Comment: So just to be shure ;) as long as this thread is running am i able to edit thigs on the page.

Comment: Yes, the user is able to modify things on the page, but there's no point of using this thread, because you can no longer act on the UI from it.

Comment: Alright thank you very much for your information, Do you have anu idee how i can update information on the screen from the codebehind after the page is rendered? Or can this only be done with javascript or somthing like that?